# malloc zero bytes for unsigned int in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){

unsigned int *p, a[25];
unsigned char *s = "goodcoffee";
unsigned int size, size1, size2, test_variable;

size1 = sizeof(unsigned int);
size2 = sizeof(unsigned int *);
size = sizeof(unsigned int)/sizeof(unsigned int *);

p = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int)/sizeof(unsigned int*));

test_variable = 0xFFFFFFFF;
*p = 0xFFFFFFFF;

strcpy(a,s);

printf("Size of int: %d , Size of int *: %d, Size: %d, Test variable:                     %d\n",size1,size2,size,test_variable);

printf("%s %d \n", a, *p);

return;

}
```

Hi, I am trying to understand why the below mentioned behavior is seen. I need your help to understand what happens with this code. Here malloc is allocating zero bytes. (This was an interview question).

output:

```
 size of int: 4,  size of int *: 4, size:1 , Test_variable: -1
 goodcoffee -1
```

I could not understand why Test_variable is showing -1 though it is an unsigned int. This happens only with the last nibble. I tried giving range of value from 0 to F as last nibble. code was giving different negative values. But if I get rid of last nibble, i.e.Test_variable is 0xFFFFFFF, the output was 268435455.

Answer (score 2):

> Here malloc is allocating zero bytes.

Malloc is not allocating `0` bytes, its allocating `1` bytes for your machine.. as

```
size = sizeof(unsigned int)/sizeof(unsigned int*) //gives 1
```

so, p is pointing to `1` byte

and

```
*p = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

you are trying to store a `4` byte number in `p` while `p` is pointing at a `1` byte allocated space. Its undefined behaviour.

Comment: The snippet you show allocates 1 byte on a typical 32bit system and 0 bytes on a typical 64bit system.

Comment: @alk: i know, i was just showing for the code that he gave.. it shows there `size = sizeof(unsigned int)/sizeof(unsigned int*)` is `1`

Comment: Ja, just saw the test output showing `sizeof (int*)` to be `4`. Sry for the noise ...

Answer (score 2):

Printf format `%d` is used to print a signed integer. Use `%u` to print an unsigned integer. The representation of the unsigned integer 0xFFFFFFFF for a signed integer is -1.

Answer (score 1):

Read more about [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html); it wants the number of bytes (not of data items), and it could fail.
So code, if `p` is supposed to contain one unsigned integer:

```
p = malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
if (!p) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
*p = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Your code incorrectly called `malloc` with either 0 or 1 *byte* which is not enough for an `unsigned int` (on *my* Debian/x86-64 machine, `sizeof(unsigned int)` is 4, and pointers want 8 bytes, so `sizeof(unsigned int*)` is 8, so `4/8` is 0).

BTW, if your system has it, use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/). Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Answer (score 0):

The negative value is stored in 2's compliment form in memory.

In your case test_variable = 0xFFFFFFFF; represent -1 in decimal.

That is what printed on the console.

Here its how it is done

```
1 represent 00000001 in binary
1's complement of 1 is 11111110
adding 1 gives 11111111=> represent ffff.
```

No of bits depends on the memory layout used by the system.